# Checking if the app is build as release

Tags: ios

I have to make sure, that the app is not sending device token for push notifications, if it build in debug, and send if in release.

Can I use this code?

```
#if RELEASE
[SendTokenRequest sendDeviceToken:deviceToken withCompletion:nil];
#endif
```

Obviously it's hard to test, it compiles and not executing in debug, just wan't to make sure it will be executed on production...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it should work in your production case, assuming `RELEASE` is preprocessor directive created only in the release build step.

I do a similar thing in the app I work on, but using a a `DEBUG` macro instead (inverting your test). I also add `#else` to ensure it is logged in debug.

```
#ifndef DEBUG
// Make sure this is executed in debug
NSLog(@"Send token in production");
#else
// Release code
#endif
```

Comment: I think your example would be:
`
#ifndef DEBUG
// Release code
NSLog(@"Send token in production");
#else
// Debug code
#endif
`
Or use #ifdef DEBUG if you want the #else to execute Release code

Answer (score 3):

You can use a flag like you want using this following method to test if you are in debug, adhoc, release or debug mode :

[image]

**Go to your Build Settings and add other flags like the previous picture.**

Next you can use that in your project (in your case) :

```
#ifdef __RELEASE__
// Do what you want
#endif
```

you can use 
`__DISTRIBUTION__`
`__RELEASE__`
`__DEBUG__`
`__AD_HOC__`
depending your scheme settings

[image]

Comment: I only have Release and Debug (no AdHoc) in those settings, why?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I found another approach. Add this pair to `Info.plist`

```
<key>Configuration</key>
<string>${CONFIGURATION}</string>
```

Now you are able to check if app is release or debug:

```
var config = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["Configuration"]
```